# Upgrading from EXPO SDK 44 to 45. IOS doesn't work but android does

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

**I have just upgraded EXPO SDK from 44 to 45.**

The issues that I am having:

- When I running the app on IOS the app is now super slow
- It also has a strange box shadow that appears on the bottom of the screen.
- Keyboard also keeps randomly poping up

[image]

The app works perfectly on android which is confusing to me. I haven't changed any of the code and on Expo SDK 44 everything was working.

What I have tried:

- Downgrading all the react packages to their previous versions apart from react-native
- Checking all API calls. In case there is a fetching issue.

These are all the packages that I am using:

```
    {
  "name": "iserve-app",
  "version": "1.25.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "lint": "tsc --noemit && eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx ./",
    "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc '**/*.{json,js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss,md}' --write"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.7",
    "@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view": "^2.0.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.2.11",
    "@types/expo": "^33.0.1",
    "@types/json-bigint": "^1.0.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "decimal.js": "^10.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint": "7.28",
    "exact-math": "^2.2.3",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-battery": "~6.2.0",
    "expo-blur": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-device": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.4",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-sensors": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.4",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "json-bigint": "^1.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "native-base": "^3.3.3",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-animated-loader": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-currency-input": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-device-detection": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-markdown-renderer": "^3.2.8",
    "react-native-network-logger": "^1.12.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.15",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^1.2.9",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-swipe-detect": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-tableview-simple": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-toast-notifications": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-native": "^6.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "semantic-release-expo": "^2.2.3",
    "sentry-expo": "^4.0.0",
    "xmldom": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^16.0.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.0.0",
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "^6.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/git": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.5",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "@types/react-router-native": "^5.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "semantic-release": "^18.0.1",
    "semantic-release-slack-bot": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Box shadow that appears:

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

try updating to the latest version: `expo-cli upgrade` or `npm audit fix --force` both of these worked on my end